# Multiple Services hosted on single Host with common Contract

Tags: c#, wcf, service

I want to achieve multiple endpoint services from single host address, all are having same Binding contract, for example my host address is

```
"net.pipe://MyUri/0"
```

and I created 3 endpoint services against it like

```
"net.pipe://MyUri/0",
"net.pipe://MyUri/0",
"net.pipe://MyUri/0"
```

Is it possible or it will cause some problem in results.

Comment: Did you try it?  Often times it's quicker and easier to try something; especially if you're not finding or getting answers from your online research.

Comment: I tried it, on last endpoint I am getting results where else every other endpoint is getting null, so I am suspecting that they are getting interrupted by other calls.